# SQL Multiple Conditions when doing LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm in the process of trying to join Table A to Table B based on different fields. When accounts are from source system "vision" i need to join using TABLE A.ACCOUNT with Table B.ACCOUNT whereas if it's from any other source system i'd use A.ID = B.ID

I've tried using

```
    SELECT
A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
A.ID_NUMBER,
A.PARTY_NUMBER,
B.ACT_CODE,
B.ID_NUMBER

FROM ACCOUNTS A

LEFT JOIN TRANS B
ON A.ID_NUMBER =  B.ID_NUMBER AND A.SOURCE <> 'VISION'

LEFT JOIN TRANS C
ON A.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT AND A.SOURCE = 'VISION'
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: `B` and `C` are poor table aliases. Choose something that makes sense. E.g. `A` for `ACCOUNTS` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR` in the join.

```
SELECT
  A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
  A.ID_NUMBER,
  A.PARTY_NUMBER,
  B.ACT_CODE,
  B.ID_NUMBER
FROM 
  ACCOUNTS A
LEFT JOIN TRANS B
  ON (A.ID_NUMBER =  B.ID_NUMBER AND A.SOURCE <> 'VISION') OR
     (A.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT AND A.SOURCE = 'VISION')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define where clause on SOURCE and Union the set of queries

```
SELECT
A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
A.ID_NUMBER,
A.PARTY_NUMBER,
B.ACT_CODE,
B.ID_NUMBER
FROM ACCOUNTS A
LEFT JOIN TRANS B
ON A.ID_NUMBER =  B.ID_NUMBER 
WHERE A.SOURCE <> 'VISION'

UNION ALL

SELECT
A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
A.ID_NUMBER,
A.PARTY_NUMBER,
B.ACT_CODE,
B.ID_NUMBER
FROM ACCOUNTS A
LEFT JOIN TRANS B
ON A.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT
WHERE A.SOURCE = 'VISION'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use cte approach:

```
  WITH df_not_vision AS
           (SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER A.ID_NUMBER, A.PARTY_NUMBER,
                   B.ACT_CODE,
                   B.ID_NUMBER
              FROM ACCOUNTS A
                       LEFT JOIN TRANS B
                                 ON A.ID_NUMBER = B.ID_NUMBER
             WHERE A.SOURCE <> 'VISION'),

       df_vision AS (SELECT A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER A.ID_NUMBER, A.PARTY_NUMBER,
                            B.ACT_CODE,
                            B.ID_NUMBER
                       FROM ACCOUNTS A
                                LEFT JOIN TRANS B
                                          ON A.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT
                      WHERE A.SOURCE = 'VISION')

SELECT *
  FROM df_not_vision

 UNION ALL

SELECT *
  FROM df_vision;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just correct the alias name in the second join condition from B.Account to C.Account